# Non orthogonal diagonal bases of normal operators

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a normal operator on unitary space $U_n$. Is there always non-orthogonal basis of $U_n$, in which $A$ is diagonal?

Comment: Hint: What if all the eigenvalues are distinct?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft If $A$ wasn't normal, this would have meant that there exists a basis in which $A$ is diagonal. But since $A$ is normal, there is even an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors...

Comment: Right, but you asked for a non-orthogonal one. Did you instead mean one that is not necessarily orthogonal?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I meant exactly what I wrote: I want to to be sure that the basis I found is not orthogonal.

Comment: Well, in that case what I wrote gives you an example of an $A$ where this is not possible.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Would you please check if my answer is correct? Should I include more details?

Comment: @GerryMyerson It is. So...? I'm asking if this claim is true $\forall A \in U_n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't always true. If all the eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct, then $(\forall \lambda \in \sigma \{ A\})\space\nu_g(\lambda)=\nu_a(\lambda)=1$. Because $A$ is normal, the eigenvectors form a orthogonal set in any basis. So then any basis of $U_n$ is orthogonal, and $A$ is diagonal in any basis.